# Shader Materials and GL Framebuffers in THREE.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl, shader, fbo

I'm trying to use an FBO in a material in THREE.js. I have a GPU-based fluid simulation which outputs its final visualisation to a framebuffer object, which I would like to use to texture a mesh. Here's my simple fragment shader:

```
varying vec2 vUv;
uniform sampler2D tDiffuse;

void main() {

    gl_FragColor = texture2D( tDiffuse, vUv );

}
```

I am then trying to use a simple THREE.ShaderMaterial:

```
var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {

    uniforms: { tDiffuse: { type: "t", value: outputFBO } },
    //other stuff... which shaders to use etc
} );
```

But my mesh just appears black, albeit with no errors to the console. If I use the same shader and shader material, but supply the result of THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("someImageOrOther") as the uniform to the shader, it renders correctly, so I assume the problem is with my FBO. Is there some convenient way of converting from an FBO to a Texture2D in WebGL?

EDIT:

After some more experimentation it would appear that this isn't the problem. If I pass the FBO to a different shader I wrote that just outputs the texture to the screen then it displays fine. Could my material appear black because of something like lighting/normals?

EDIT 2:

The UVs and normals are coming straight from THREE, so I don't think it can be that. Part of the problem is that most shader errors aren't reported so I have difficulty in that regard. If I could just map the WebGLTexture somehow that would make everything easier, perhaps like this

```
var newMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ map : outputFBO.texture });
```

but of course that doesn't work. I haven't been able to find any documentation that suggests THREE can read directly from WebGLTextures.

Comment: It's called "render to texture". http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_rtt.html

Comment: Sorry, I think you have misunderstood me. I am already drawing to a texture (actually an FBO containing a texture). I do not have a problem with that. What I am trying to do now is to use this WebGLTexture to texture a mesh in THREE.js

Comment: The example I referenced is doing exactly that. It is rendering to a WebGLRenderTarget and using the WebGLRenderTarget as a texture for the material for a mesh.

Comment: That is not the same thing. That example demonstrates THREE's renderer drawing to a THREE.WebGLRenderTarget. I have a separate system for drawing to a GL data structure (eg WebGLTexture or WebGLFramebuffer, as documented in the full WebGL spec [http://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/]) - if I could use THREE's data structures (as in that example) then I would.

Comment: Yes, I was suggesting you use three.js data structures. I understand now that using your data structure is a hard constraint.

Answer (score 0):

By poking a little into the sources of WebGLRenderer (look at https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/renderers/WebGLRenderer.js#L6643 and after), you may try to create a three js texture with a dummy picture, then change the data member `__webglTexture` of this texture by putting your own webgltexture.

Also, you may need to set to `true` the `__webglInit` data member of the texture object so that init code is not executed (because then `__webglTexture` is overwritten by a call to `_gl.createTexture();`)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using the Three.js data structures, here's how you do it:

[Three.js use framebuffer as texture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21533757/three-js-use-framebuffer-as-texture/21651562#21651562)